# Автоматическая смена цвета у блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне очень нравится фишка с сайта [Артемия Лебедева](https://www.artlebedev.ru/), где в шапке у них логотип. Так вот этот логотип со временем медленно меняет свой цвет, а при наведении курсора меняет на другой сразу и, что немаловажно, не меняется обратно (как бывает с типичными скриптами).

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять процесс создания оного (хотя бы одной из этих двух фишек)! Что это, JS или Jquery?

Comment: вы откройте html код страницы, и изучите, что там происходит с логотипом этим

Comment: Ничего такого, что может быть "двигателем скрипта" не нашёл:

`<div id="als-logo" style="background-color: rgb(112, 50, 96);"></div>`

А css показывает только это и прочие стили:

`element.style {
    background-color: rgb(112, 50, 96);
}`

Прога Visual Event показывает вот это:

`function g(){n.h=Math.floor(360*Math.random()),n.s=30+Math.floor(70*Math.random()),n.v=30+Math.floor(50*Math.random()),f(n.h,n.s,n.v.)`

Comment: Анимация логотипа осуществляется с помощью JS в этом файле.
https://img.artlebedev.ru/svalka/header-2016/v2/rev_1489415349/main.min.js
Если хотите, можете его декопрессить и попробовать разобраться

Comment: @NickVolynkin я не могу писать коментарии к удаленным ответам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```js
let logo = document.getElementById('als-logo');

function changeBackground(color) {
   logo.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function getRandomColor () {
  var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
  return "#" + ("000000" + hex.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}

logo.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
 logo.classList.remove('trs');
  console.log('1')
 changeBackground(getRandomColor());
  setTimeout(() => {logo.classList.add('trs');},100);
});

setInterval(() => {
 changeBackground(getRandomColor());
}, 1000);
```

```css
#als-logo {
  background: url('https://img.artlebedev.ru/svalka/logo-v5/als-logo-01.png') top left no-repeat #f90710;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 90px 30px;
}

.trs {
  transition: 7s;
}
```

```html
<div id="als-logo" class='trs' style="background-color: rgb(149, 151, 16);"></div>
```

Comment: БРАВО! Вы великолепны )

Answer (score 3):

Там на JS, лучше заюзать CSS-анимацию:

```js
let logo = document.querySelector('#logo');

// Генерируем и устанавливаем рандомный фон
const setRandomBg = _ => logo.style.background = Array(...Array(6)).reduce(_ => _ += '0123456789ABCDEF'[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)], '#');

// При наведении курсора на объект
logo.addEventListener('mouseenter', _ => {
  // Ставим новый цвет
  setRandomBg();
  // Перезапускаем анимацию (да, на хак похоже, но увы, пока что есть)
  logo.classList.remove('anim');
  setTimeout(_ => logo.classList.add('anim'), 10);
});
// По окончании итерации анимации, меняем фон
logo.addEventListener('animationiteration', _ => setRandomBg());

setRandomBg();
```

```css
#logo{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}

.anim{
  animation: bs 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes bs{
  0%{
    filter: brightness(1);
  }
  100%{
    filter: brightness(.6);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='logo' class='anim'></div>
```

Comment: Ого! Круто, хоть на том спасибо!

Comment: @ЗаурГитинов, "хоть на том"?

Comment: хотел сказать, что то, что вы сделали будет достаточно )

Answer (score 1):

Логотип этот состоит из двух слоев. `div` с залитым ровным цветом и поверх него наложены белые буквы картинкой:

```css
.fon {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #903;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class=fon><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mejn.png"></div>
```

Поскольку фон задается через CSS нет проблем его поменять:

```
$('.fon').css('background',"hsv("+h+", "+s+", "+v);
```

осталось подобрать значения (берем то что вы нарыли на сайте):

```
h=Math.floor(360*Math.random());
s=30+Math.floor(70*M‌​ath.random());
v=30‌​+Math.floor(50*Math.‌​random());
```

Собираем из этого функцию, и вызываем ее

```
//меняем цвет при наведении
$(".fon").mouseover(changecolor)

//меняем цвет по таймеру
setInterval(changecolor,10000)
```

Плавную смену цвета можно добавить используя `transition` в css:

```
transition: background ease .7s
```

## Рабочий пример:

```js
function changecolor() {
  h = Math.floor(360 * Math.random());
  s = 30 + Math.floor(70 * Math.random());
  v = 30 + Math.floor(50 * Math.random());
  $('.fon').css('background', "hsl(" + h + ", " + s + "%, " + v + "% )");
}

//меняем цвет при наведении
$(".fon").mouseover(changecolor);


//меняем цвет по таймеру
setInterval(changecolor,10000);


//меняем цвет при загрузке
changecolor();
```

```css
.fon {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #903;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background ease .7s
}
   .fon img {pointer-events:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=fon><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mejn.png"></div>
```

Comment: 1) Где анимация? 2) Почему цвет меняется при входе и выходе?

Comment: То что плавной анимации нет— не страшно. Но смена цветов не совсем та ((

Comment: @ЗаурГитинов исправил ответ